# How to get response content even if connection gives error in IdHttp?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, idhttp

When using TIdHttp like this:

```
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.post(url,data);
```

I can get response content to memo1 if it doesn't give http error. But when it gives http bad request, Indy doesn't give me content. I'm also using try..except but it only prevent error box and still doesn't give me content.

How can I get content even it returns http error?

Comment: no I mean when it gives http bad request 400 I can see its response content in Fiddler so it definitely send content but I cannot get it in delphi. delphi just gives error.

Comment: in this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762584/post-problems-with-indy-tidhttp#comment9481513_7769356) you say "Firefox displays the content even if he get HTTP 400 Bad Request error. E.g. Internet Explorer tell you that bad request happened and doesn't display the XML content response, Indy works the same, create the error message and throw away the content." i think my problem is exactly that.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` does not throw away the content. It is placed in the exception that is raised. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

When an HTTP error occurs, `TIdHTTP` raises an  `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception. That exception contains the HTTP status code in its `ErrorCode` property, the HTTP status text in its `Message` property, and the response data in its `ErrorMessage` property.

Comment: thanks for answer. when I disabled hoNoProtocolErrorException ErrorMessage gave me response data.

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
Try
    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.post(url,data);
except on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
begin
    memo1.lines.add(idHTTP1.response.ResponseText);
    memo1.lines.add(e.ErrorMessage);
end;
```

e.ErrorMessage will give you some informations about the bad request.

Comment: Then don't include the 2nd memo1.lines.add line.

Comment: ResponseText is not "content". It's just status text. I need content.

Comment: thanks for this answer. it was my mistake. when i disabled hoNoProtocolErrorException, ErrorMessage gave me response content.