# Posting Form Data With idHTTP in Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, indy

I'm using Delphi with IdHTTP lib to get a form from this URL (http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au), handle the puzzle and post with the correct answer. But, apparently I am not handling the method POST properly, once the response retrieved is: "Problem with submission. Please try again."

Below is the Delphi source code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sGET, sPOST, sGET_count: String;
  countCircles: integer;
  parameters: TStringList;
begin
  parameters := TStringList.Create;
  sGET := http.Get('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au');
  sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET, '$', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET_count, 'unfilled', '$', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  countCircles := 120 - sGET_count.CountChar('$');

  parameters.Add('title=submit');
  parameters.Add('value=' + countCircles.ToString());
  parameters.Add('submit=Submit');
  http.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  sPOST := http.Post('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/?', parameters);
  txtPost.Lines.Add(sPOST);
end;
```

[Form retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X4xa.png)

HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="title" value="submit">
      <p>How many filled circles do you see:? <br><img src="unfilled_O.gif" height="12" width="12"><br></p>
      <p>Answer: <input type="text" name="value" value="" size="10"></p>
      <p><input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form></body>
</html>
```

Response retrieved from POST method:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Problem with submission. Please try again.</p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a HTTP proxy to capture your browser communication and to see how a "working" request looks like

Comment: any program that you would recommend?

Comment: no need for that, use F12 function in any modern browser (or use firebug with firefox) and check out the network request.

Comment: It seems that you did not set the `TIdHttp.Request.ContentType` (should be `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`). See also this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7769356/1744164

Comment: Trying the same method POST through Chrome:
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/18sVk.png

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help me. I just set the ContentType but I'm still with the same problem.

Comment: Have you read my answer (and edit)?

Comment: @SirRufo: The `TStrings` version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` automatically sets the `Request.ContentType` to `application/x-www.webform-urlencoded` if it has not already been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I see no problem with your `TIdHTTP` code (although the `/?` on the end of the URL for the `Post()` is not necessary).</strike>  There are missing steps in your `TIdHTTP` code.  See further below for details.

I also see a problem with your `StringReplace()` code:

> ```pascal
> sGET := http.Get('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au');
> sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET, '$', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
> sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET, 'unfilled', '$', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
> ```

Notice the first parameter of the second `StringReplace()`.  In that second call, you are searching the **original HTML** that is returned by `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  You are not searching the result of the first `StringReplace()`.  And then you are discarding the result of the first `StringReplace()` altogether when you re-assign `sGET_count`, effectively making the first call a no-op.  You probably meant to do this instead:

```pascal
sGET := http.Get('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au');
sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET, '$', ' ', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
sGET_count := StringReplace({sGET}sGET_count, 'unfilled', '$', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

**Update**: when I visit the URL in my webbrowser, I found a couple of things that your code is not taking into account.  One, the webform includes a `jobref` field that you are not including in your `POST` submission.  But more importantly, the webpage in question invokes a JavaScript function when the webpage is retrieved by a real webbrowser, but not when retrieved by your current `TIdHTTP` setup. That Javascript is located at `http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au/funcs1.js` and contains a single command to dynamically add a cookie to the webbrowser:

```js
function init() {
  document.cookie = 'pc3o=d2r22; path=';
}
```

This command is invoked by the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="funcs1.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onLoad="init()">
  ...
  </html>
```

That extra cookie gets sent back to the webserver when the webbrowser submits the webform, in addition to a normal PHP cookie that is present in the HTTP headers when the HTML is retrieved.  You need to set the `TIdHTTP.AllowCookies` property to True (it is False by default) so `TIdHTTP.Post()` can send back the cookies, however `Post()` will only send the PHP cookie by default, not the Javascript cookie, for obvious reasons (`TIdHTTP` does not invoke client-side scripts).

If you change the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property to mimic a real webbrowser, instead of using Indy's default `UserAgent`, the downloaded HTML will include that JavaScript reference.  This is optional, as you can manually add the Javascript cookie (fortunately it is static, so you don't need to actually parse the Javascript, but you can if you want to) to the `TIdHTTP.CookieManager` regardless of the `UserAgent`, and `Post()` will still send it, and the server doesn't seem to care if the HTML included the JavaScript reference or not.

With that said, the following code works for me (I got the server to send a successful response to the `POST`):

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sGET, sPOST, sGET_count: String;
  countCircles: integer;
  parameters: TStringList;
begin
  parameters := TStringList.Create;
  try
    http.AllowCookies := True;
    // optional: http.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

    sGET := http.Get('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au');
    http.CookieManager.AddServerCookie('pc3o=d2r22; path=', http.URL);

    sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET, '$', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    sGET_count := StringReplace(sGET_count, '"filled_O.gif"', '$', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    countCircles := sGET_count.CountChar('$');

    parameters.Add('title=submit');
    parameters.Add('jobref=');
    parameters.Add('value=' + countCircles.ToString());

    http.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    http.Request.Referer := 'http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au';

    sPOST := http.Post('http://apply.dataprocessors.com.au', parameters);
    ShowMessage(sPOST);
  finally
    parameters.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's true, the second StringReplace() was wrong, what I meant is exactly what you explained. But the first StringReplace() is just for safety, just in case there is "$" in the HTML that would spoil the math. As expected, even fixing this I'm still getting the same message. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: really interesting. Referring to "*If you change the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property to mimic a real webbrowser, instead of using Indy's default `UserAgent`, the downloaded HTML will include that JavaScript reference.*" would you be kind enough to explain why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some webservers send different content to different user agents. Some browsers have quirks/behaviors that differ from other browsers, so sometimes webpage authors create browser-specific content, browser-specific scripts, etc.  In this case, `apply.dataprocessors.com.au` is apparently useragent-aware, because it tweaks the HTML based on different `User-Agent` header values.

Comment: *apparently* too much *useragent-aware* :D So obvious that I couldn't figure it out. Thank you again sir

Comment: Allowing and adding the cookie worked. Thanks for your help and excellent explanation about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use F12 (or a HTTP proxy) to capture your browser communication and to see how a "working" request looks like.

Does the working request use cookies? If yes, enable cookie support for IdHttp.

Comment: I checked the method POST on google chrome and I'm getting the same response already, but just while sending the wrong answer for the puzzle. When I send the right answer I get: Problem with submission. Please try again.

Comment: Actually, you are sending the right answer, you are just not sending everything that the server is expecting you to send.  See my answer for details.